# Troubleshooting and resolving FPS drop in games

Tags: nvidia, kernel, graphics

My desktop running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS is having FPS issues lately. On games from both ,Steam and GoG, my FPS have dropped significantly. Table Top Simulator was at least 60 FPS now its 10 in the menu and worse from there.
Rimworld, which I have downloaded from GoG, now runs noticeably slower as well. In addition, the PC doesn't seem to wake it after I suspend it. Everything lights up, but no UI or anything is shown. I have to restart the computer.

So this is either a hardware issue or an OS/version/Drivers based issue from what I can tell.

How should I go about testing the GPU to confirm whether it is failing?

How should I go about seeing if an updated affected my FPS?

I have a GeForce GTX 960, using the Nvidia-driver-535 drivers (the latest, from what I can tell, and what I believe I've used for a while)

Other useful information:
Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
cpu: AMD Ryzen 5 5600 6-Core Processor
Board: TUF GAMING B550M-PLUS (WI-FI)
Storage: SSD

If any additional information is needed, please let me know

Edit: I'm using Xorg based on an output of X11 from running echo `$XDG_SESSION_TYPE`

Contents of /var/log/apt/history.log:

```
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.118'
Upgrade: thunderbird:amd64 (1:115.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 1:115.6.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), thunderbird-locale-en:amd64 (1:115.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 1:115.6.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), thunderbird-locale-en-us:amd64 (1:115.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 1:115.6.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), thunderbird-gnome-support:amd64 (1:115.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 1:115.6.0+build2-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-01-02  09:59:41

Start-Date: 2024-01-03  15:10:22
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.122'
Upgrade: openssh-client:amd64 (1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.5, 1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.6), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (120.0.6099.129-1, 120.0.6099.199-1), libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.37.2-2ubuntu0.1, 3.37.2-2ubuntu0.3)
End-Date: 2024-01-03  15:10:28

Start-Date: 2024-01-10  22:16:46
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.121'
Install: nvidia-firmware-535-535.146.02:amd64 (535.146.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1+4, automatic), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1+4, automatic), linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-14:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1, automatic), linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: google-chrome-stable:amd64 (120.0.6099.199-1, 120.0.6099.216-1), linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.2.0.39.40~22.04.16, 6.5.0.14.14~22.04.7), software-properties-common:amd64 (0.99.22.8, 0.99.22.9), python3-software-properties:amd64 (0.99.22.8, 0.99.22.9), libc6:amd64 (2.35-0ubuntu3.5, 2.35-0ubuntu3.6), libc6:i386 (2.35-0ubuntu3.5, 2.35-0ubuntu3.6), locales:amd64 (2.35-0ubuntu3.5, 2.35-0ubuntu3.6), software-properties-gtk:amd64 (0.99.22.8, 0.99.22.9), linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.2.0.39.40~22.04.16, 6.5.0.14.14~22.04.7), linux-generic-hwe-22.04:amd64 (6.2.0.39.40~22.04.16, 6.5.0.14.14~22.04.7), python3-distro-info:amd64 (1.1ubuntu0.1, 1.1ubuntu0.2), distro-info-data:amd64 (0.52ubuntu0.5, 0.52ubuntu0.6), linux-firmware:amd64 (20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.23, 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.24), distro-info:amd64 (1.1ubuntu0.1, 1.1ubuntu0.2), libc-dev-bin:amd64 (2.35-0ubuntu3.5, 2.35-0ubuntu3.6), brave-browser:amd64 (1.61.109, 1.61.116), libc-bin:amd64 (2.35-0ubuntu3.5, 2.35-0ubuntu3.6), libc-devtools:amd64 (2.35-0ubuntu3.5, 2.35-0ubuntu3.6), libc6-dbg:amd64 (2.35-0ubuntu3.5, 2.35-0ubuntu3.6), libc6-dev:amd64 (2.35-0ubuntu3.5, 2.35-0ubuntu3.6)
End-Date: 2024-01-10  22:18:49

Start-Date: 2024-01-10  22:24:05
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.121'
Remove: linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1), linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.2.0-37-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1), linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-37:amd64 (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1), linux-signatures-nvidia-6.2.0-37-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1), linux-modules-6.2.0-37-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1), linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1), linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1), linux-modules-nvidia-535-6.2.0-37-generic:amd64 (6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1)
End-Date: 2024-01-10  22:24:14

Start-Date: 2024-01-11  16:59:34
Commandline: apt install mesa-utils
Requested-By: danny (1000)
Install: mesa-utils-bin:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1, automatic), mesa-utils:amd64 (8.4.0-1ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2024-01-11  16:59:35

Start-Date: 2024-01-16  20:54:22
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.186'
Upgrade: update-manager:amd64 (1:22.04.10, 1:22.04.18), libctf-nobfd0:amd64 (2.38-4ubuntu2.4, 2.38-4ubuntu2.5), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (120.0.6099.216-1, 120.0.6099.224-1), xserver-xorg-core:amd64 (2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5, 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7), libbinutils:amd64 (2.38-4ubuntu2.4, 2.38-4ubuntu2.5), transmission-gtk:amd64 (3.00-2ubuntu2, 3.00-2ubuntu2.1), gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu:amd64 (2.38-4ubuntu2.4, 2.38-4ubuntu2.5), gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), xserver-xorg-legacy:amd64 (2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5, 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7), dnsmasq-base:amd64 (2.86-1.1ubuntu0.3, 2.86-1.1ubuntu0.4), xserver-common:amd64 (2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5, 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7), xwayland:amd64 (2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.9, 2:22.1.1-1ubuntu0.10), update-manager-core:amd64 (1:22.04.10, 1:22.04.18), libctf0:amd64 (2.38-4ubuntu2.4, 2.38-4ubuntu2.5), libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), binutils-common:amd64 (2.38-4ubuntu2.4, 2.38-4ubuntu2.5), xserver-xephyr:amd64 (2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.5, 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.7), python3-update-manager:amd64 (1:22.04.10, 1:22.04.18), transmission-common:amd64 (3.00-2ubuntu2, 3.00-2ubuntu2.1), libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.42.3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, 2.42.4-0ubuntu0.22.04.1), binutils:amd64 (2.38-4ubuntu2.4, 2.38-4ubuntu2.5)
End-Date: 2024-01-16  20:54:32

Start-Date: 2024-01-16  21:13:44
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: danny (1000)
Upgrade: systemd-hwe-hwdb:amd64 (249.11.4, 249.11.5)
End-Date: 2024-01-16  21:13:45

Start-Date: 2024-01-16  21:23:00
Commandline: apt-get install lm-sensors
Requested-By: danny (1000)
Install: lm-sensors:amd64 (1:3.6.0-7ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2024-01-16  21:23:02

Start-Date: 2024-01-17  12:55:11
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.199'
Upgrade: libpam-runtime:amd64 (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3, 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4), tzdata:amd64 (2023c-0ubuntu0.22.04.2, 2023d-0ubuntu0.22.04), libpam-modules:amd64 (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3, 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4), libpam-modules-bin:amd64 (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3, 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4), libpam0g:amd64 (1.4.0-11ubuntu2.3, 1.4.0-11ubuntu2.4), brave-browser:amd64 (1.61.116, 1.61.120)
End-Date: 2024-01-17  12:55:20
```

I know for sure that my computer was working fine on the 5th of January. By the 11th, I had noticed my FPS issues. Based on the above list of changes, I would suspect the change was to the nvidia-firmware done on 2024-01-10. I would need to figure out how to test, undoing that update to see if that caused the issue.

After looking online a bit more, it appears that nvidia-535-6.5.0-14 kernal is the problem. I rebooted my PC, and in the grub menu, selected the kernal before. My FPS are back to normal. That kernal version was added on 1/10 in my system which coincides with when I started to encounter issues. I'll be looking at steps for setting an alternative Kernal as default until a new kernal comes out. I'm not quite certain how to track when a new kernal comes out though, or if my OS would tell me (doubt it).

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackExchange. Can you confirm if you are running on Xorg or Wayland? I.e. When you login, click the cog wheel on the bottom-right of the login screen, and if you are running proprietary Nvidia drivers, the login default choices are 1) "Ubuntu" (meaning Xorg), and 2) "Ubuntu on Wayland". Use Xorg and see if your issue is fixed. IF so, then we can post an official answer.

Comment: The 22.04.4 changes have started rolling out, one of the first changes is the switch of HWE installs from 6.2 kernel (22.04.3) to 6.5; which of course changes kernel modules too (aka *drivers*).. If you're aware of when change occurred; contrast with what change(s) you installed prior to change; `/var/log/apt/history.log` (ie. your description made me think of kernel stack update for example).. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS being a LTS release has kernel stack options.

Comment: @sarlacii I ran the command:
`echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` and got a response of X11 which should mean I'm using Xorg. I didn't see a cog wheel on the bottom right of my login screen.

Comment: @guiverc I have added the contents of my */history.log file in the OP. It appears there was a change done on nvidia-firmware on 1/10 which I suspect could be the cause, as my issues occurred sometime between the 5th of January and the 11th of January.
How would I go about undoing the change?

Comment: @guiverc your comment led me to finding the answer. Seems like a kernal issue. I'd be happy to give you credit for helping me find the answer, though it seems that you need to provide an answer instead of a comment to my post.

Comment: Please write your own answer, and then accept it (*and thus gain rep*).  If you'd like to mention me in that answer (ie. give me credit*) feel free, but *Well done!* on solving your issue. I suspect an answer by you, what you did (*commands, output and your discovery of problem/answer including how it was fixed*) would benefit future users better than my vague *comments* (as answer).  Use https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack if useful for details as to kernel stack (HWE, GA etc).   Again *Well done* on solving your issue.

Comment: FYI:  You can install & use both GA + HWE kernel stacks; however certain closed-source kernel modules (esp. many nvidia modules) can prevent both stacks co-existing on an install.  On most of my boxes (*running LTS*) I have both stacks installed, so if I have issues with 6.5 for example; I'd just select the GA/5.15 kernel instead on next boot (*given its supported & thus fully-patched too for security issues etc*).

Comment: Nicely done user3041883. The cog sits by the username in 20.04, and is not there in 22.04. :( My apologies! But you figured out how to do the check anyway. I like guiverc's suggestion that you write a short answer. I'll give it a tick.

Comment: @sarlacii I believe that it wasn't showing up for me before because of the kernal issues.
Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the issue seems to stem from a new kernal that was pushed out that is causing problems.

This [post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494273&page=2&p=14175164#post14175164) from MAFoElffen from the ubuntu forums helped me resolve my issue while I await for a new kernal. Relevant portion pasted later below along with my additions:

I believe I'm using a legacy driver, due to my graphics card being so old. You can view , what I believe to be, an incomplete list of legacy driver devices in this [link](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/legacy-gpu/) from Nvidia. I say incomplete because mine doesn't show up on the list.

Before following MAFoElffen's steps to resolve my issues I did the following and suggest the same to others:

- Reboot your computer to access grub menu.
- Select advanced options for Ubuntu
- Select the most recent Kernal that is not 6.5.0-14 (6.2.0-39-generic in my case)
- boot with that kernal
- Confirm this kernal functions correctly as you will set this kernal as your default in the next steps. (my FPS issues were resolved with this kernal)

Now to MAFoElffen's steps:

> Legacy Drivers: Use 6.2.0 series kernels...
> Code:

```
sudo apt remove --purge --yes linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic linux-image-6.5.0-14-generic linux-modules-6.5.0-14-generic linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic
sudo apt install --reinstall --yes linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-39-generic
sudo apt-mark hold linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-39-generic
```

[The above appears to remove the newest driver to prevent the system from booting to it, reinstalls the working kernal and holds it meaning it won't be upgraded nor removed]

> When they come up with a fix to compile NVidia Legacy drivers with Linux kernel 6.5 series kernels, then you can re-add that kernel series by unpinning the kernels via
> Code:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold linux-headers-6.2.0-39-generic linux-image-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-39-generic linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-39-generic
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Since you should already be on the working kernal, your system should already be working. Restarting your computer is unnecessary and your system will automatically boot with this working kernal in the future.

**How I found my solution:**

thanks to @guiverc for helping me figure out how to check past upgrades.
View the file in /var/log/apt/history.log

I know that my system was working normally on January 5th, but that by January 11th, it was not working. Looking at the */history.log file, I could see a couple changes that were potentially problematic but this is the one I focused on:

```
Start-Date: 2024-01-10  22:16:46
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.121'
Install: nvidia-firmware-535-535.146.02:amd64 (535.146.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1, automatic), linux-objects-nvidia-535-6.5.0-14-generic:amd64 (6.5.0-14.14~22.04.1+4, automatic), 
[...]
End-Date: 2024-01-10  22:18:49
```

I saw Nvidia-firmware which speaks to me as a kernal/GPU change which would cuase my problems.
I then started to search up the versions listed to see if any problems have been reported online.
I didn't want to include the text parts (nvidia-firmware*) because I wasn't sure if any references would include that, vs I'm certain the version number would be included.

535-535.146.02 returned nothing useful ( I didn't include the full name while searching, in order to not accidentally limit my search)

But searching with 6.5.0-14 did turn up a post in the nvidia forums which led to a [post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494273) in the ubuntu forums where I found my fix.

For newer GPUs using non legacy drivers (does not apply to me), the user MAFoElffen asserts that the driver was compiled with gcc-11 when it needed to be compiled with gcc-12. He goes through the steps on how to temporarily switch to gcc-12 and reinstall the 6.5 drivers, and switch back the default compiler to gcc-11.

**Things I learned**

/var/log/apt/history.log file is extremely helpful for troubleshooting.

Temporarily changing to an older kernal is an easy step to see if the issue may be kernal related.

Hope this helps others.